# AngularJS - jQuery UI datepicker with alternative input not firing ng-model

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker, with an alternative input.

So, when selecting a date from the calendar, an inputs value is set by jQuery.

The value is being updated in the input, but the ng-model is not updating.

```
<input type="text" name="date"  ng-model="user.date" />
```

Comment: You should look into using [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/). JQuery isn't really needed when using Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`.trigger('input');`

`ngModel` listens for `input` event, so to make it work you have to fire an event .

```
$('input[name="date"]').trigger('input');
```

Comment: I've thought of this, but it didn't quite seem the angularjs way of things. Is this the best way of doing it? Thanks

Comment: @CharliePrynn if you are doing it with jQuery you have do it. or you do all with AngularJs